# Subject (a class) returns itself in a method

Tags: class, testing, rspec

I'm doing an exercise on a course and I have to write code to make the following test pass:

```
  it 'returns itself when exiting a journey' do
    expect(subject.finish(station)).to eq(subject)
  end
```

I've written:

```
    class Journey
      ...
      def finish(station)
        Journey
      end
      ...
    end
```

I get the error:

```
expected: #<Journey:0x00007fd90091e7c8>
            got: Journey

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -#<Journey:0x00007fd90091e7c8>
       +Journey
```

It felt a bit too easy when I was writing it but I'm not sure how else to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a class

```rb
      def finish(station)
        Journey
      end
```

but you need to return an instance:

```rb
      def finish(station)
        Journey.new
      end
```

But that's not good enough yet, because you need to return the same instance as the object on which the method was called on"

```rb
      def finish(station)
        self
      end
```

Comment: I've done it and it's all working fine! All tests passing. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO and wasn't aware. I've clicked the green tick as I assume that's what you mean by accept? Thanks, again!

Comment: Yes @PaulM, welcome to SO and thanks for the accept - it gives me 15 internet points ;)